# Python two dimensional list to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column and its value for a row is like 
    `[["x","1"],["y","2"],["z","3"]]`

I want to append these values to my dataframe as first element of the inner list being column name, and the second element of the inner list  being the associated value.

For example, for the data above, my dataframe should have column named `"x"` and it's value should be `"1"` (same for the "y","z" and their respective values).Moreover, I want to do this for every row in the dataframe, and if a row doesn't have `"x"`(or any other character), its value should be 0.

Is there any proper way to do that?

Comment: You could simply make a `dict` out of it, then use this dict to create your df

Comment: To confirm, you have a dataframe with a single column with values that are lists of 3 elements? Why not just have a dataframe with 3 columns?

Comment: There are also another columns, but I want to perform this task for one specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
a = [["x","1"],["y","2"],["z","3"]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":a, 'b':range(3)})

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k1:{k:v} for k1, (k, v) in df['col'].items()}, orient='index')
print (df1)
     x    y    z
0    1  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    2  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    3

df = df.join(df1.fillna(0))
print (df)
      col  b  x  y  z
0  [x, 1]  0  1  0  0
1  [y, 2]  1  0  2  0
2  [z, 3]  2  0  0  3
```